# Logging in to Instagram without Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to get the page source for an Instagram post using the code below. Funnily enough, it worked a few times but then it said that I wasn't logged in (which changes the entire source code). Is there any way so that I can access the source code? You would get while logged in without using automation stuff like Selenium, because that would be pretty slow.

```
import requests
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen, URLError, Request


def getSource(rawLink):

    req = Request(
        rawLink,
        data = None,
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36"
        }
    )

    with urlopen(req) as response:

        source = response.read().decode('utf-8')

    return source


link = "https://www.instagram.com/p/COF47v4HoC9/"
source = getSource(link)

print(source[0:100])
```

As you can see the output line `<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">` indicates how I'm not logged in.

Comment: >"without using automation stuff" - Do you want to do it manually instead? There are many other automation alternatives apart from Selenium, but if you don't want to automate at all then what is your goal?

Comment: @isopach The thing is that I only need the page source you get while you're logged in and I'm not intending to do anything else using browser automation hence using libraries like Selenium would not be a good idea since they're pretty slow. I'm basically looking for any other way using faster libraries. I apologize if my question was too ambiguous.

Comment: Please be more clear on what kind of solution are you expecting